# Python simple DNS resolver: memory leak

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is a DNS resolver that check from a DB for an entry not older than 5 minutes.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from MySQLdb import _mysql as MySQL
from dnslib import RR, QTYPE, RCODE, A
from dnslib.label import DNSLabel
from dnslib.server import DNSServer, BaseResolver
from time import sleep, time


class MariaResolver(BaseResolver):
    DELTA = 300

    def __init__(self):
        self.password = "********************"

    def resolve(self, request, handler):
        reply = request.reply()
        qname = request.q.qname
        fqdn = str(request.q.qname)
        try:
            if fqdn.find("iut-") == -1:
                reply.header.rcode = RCODE.REFUSED
            else:
                hostname = fqdn.split(".")[0]
                timestamp = int(time()) - self.DELTA
                query = "SELECT ip FROM dns WHERE record='{}' AND timestamp>{}"
                db = MySQL.connect("localhost", "dns", self.password, "salles")
                db.query(query.format(hostname, timestamp))
                result = db.store_result()
                row = result.fetch_row(how=1)
                if row:
                    ip = row[0]["ip"].decode("utf-8")
                    reply.add_answer(RR(qname, QTYPE.A, ttl=0,
                                        rdata=A(ip)))
                else:
                    reply.header.rcode = RCODE.REFUSED
                db.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            reply.header.rcode = RCODE.REFUSED
        return reply

if __name__ == '__main__':
    resolver = MariaResolver()
    udp_server = DNSServer(resolver, port=53)
    udp_server.start_thread()
    while udp_server.isAlive():
        sleep(0.1)
```

This code leaks over time and I do not understand why.

In the Proxmox screenshot, you can see service restarted at the and.

[image: Proxmox]

Comment: Did you try to look for a memory leak? Some resources: https://web.archive.org/web/20160316152429/http://www.lshift.net/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks/ and https://www.fugue.co/blog/diagnosing-and-fixing-memory-leaks-in-python.html

Comment: I would indeed run a profiler, but my initial thought is when an exception is raised and caught the call to `db.close()` isn't occurring. You're likely leaving a database connection open each time.  I would move the `close()` to `finally`